# Fitting snakes in a cage

Tags: no-computers, optimization

11 snakes are in a 6x11 rectangular cage (grid) in a zoo.
Each snake is a different length, from 1 to 11.
No snakes may overlap. No spaces are empty.
Each of the 6 rows may contain at most 2 snake heads (so that guests may see them better).
Each of the 11 columns must contain exactly 1 snake head  (so that guests may see them better).
No two snake heads may be orthogonally adjacent (or they will eat each other).

A snake is 1 cell wide and N cells long, with a head at one end, and may bend at right angles.

[image: example]

But the snakes prefer to stretch out...

**What is the minimum total number of right angles of all the snakes combined that is required to fit them properly into the cage?**

(There are many configurations - just need the minimum # and an example).

Comment: I found a trivial solution with no bends, but I'm not sure how to format it, since the spoiler tags don't support tables. EDIT: nevermind, I think the snakes will eat each other.

Comment: @Someone you could format with the `<CODE>` markup and use letters: uppercase for the heads and lowercase for their bodies.

Comment: Yes, but then newlines wouldn't work, because spoiler tags are wack.

Comment: @Someone Use ```<pre></pre>``` tags for fixed-width font.

Comment: Oh, preformat tags. Hadn't thought of that. But my answer is wrong because of the no-adjacent-heads rule.

Comment: @Someone please see my formatting example.

Comment: Apparently multiline <pre> tags work as well, so I could do that. However, my answer is invalid, so I can't really post anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number is

> 5

Example, thanks @Magma for the nice picture:

> [image]

Proof of minimality:

The snake heads delineate 15 nonempty horizontal subrows. Indeed, there are 5 rows with two and one row with one head in it. This yields 17 segments two of which are empty (heads in first or last column). The others are nonempty because the heads are not allowed to touch.

These 15 subrows need to be covered by 10 snake bodies (snake 1 is only head hence doesn't contribute). Each snake body can be decomposed into at most #of right angles + 1 straight line segments.

We need to show that a given number k of such line segments can at most cover k subrows. For horizontal segments this is clear because they cannot extend across heads.

Vertical segments can cover only one colmun each. But because subrows are delineated by distinct columns the total number of columns that needs to be covered is at least equal to the number of subrows. This can be seen by sorting them by their right boundaries in ascending or their left boundaries  in decreasing order and observing that in this order each subrow contributes new columns.

Comment: brilliant work!